# FullPage.js autosliding in iExplore

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web, cross-browser, fullpage.js

My website hosted at [kylehb](http://www.kylehb.com)

The website works as intended on both Chrome and FireFox, but in iExplorer it automatically loops the slides(pages) and reverts to the first one if you try navigate to any other slide.

Im using fullPage.js

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of fullpage.js which contained a bug. (1.6.8)

Please download [the latest one fullpage.js 1.7.8](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

The internal functions `addTouchHandler` and `removeTouchHandler` have changed since then and sounds to be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply sorry for the delayed response!

Comment: @KyleMHB if it solved your problem you should accept the answer in case someone else has the same problem and end up here.

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm using the latest version of fullpage.js (2.2.6) with a template created with Bootstrap 3 In all browsers it works fine, but with Explorer 11 in Windows 8.1 make autosliding each page section.

Comment: @JosephCollins are you talking about a touch device? I've tested the [demo site](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage) in windows 8.1 over IE 11 and it works properly.

Comment: @Alvaro I tested on a HP Pavilion 11 x360 ( This machine is a convertible device with touch screen ). The demo site of the plugin have same issue with this machine, unfortunately until I finish making the template I noticed this issue =/

Comment: @JosephCollins it is already known that it doesn't work in Tablets with windows 8. https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/670 No solution found yet.